# Are there any Cyberspace sections in System Shock (2023) that are mandatory prior to final boss level?

Tags: system-shock-2023

I System Shock (2023), most cyberspace sections appear to be optional. They either provide you with shortcuts through levels by unlocking doors and so on, or they give you access to areas with additional in game items such as ammunition.

Prior to the final battle with Shodan, are there any cyberspace sections that cannot be skipped, and which must be completed in order to reach Shodan?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the final one on the Bridge, there are several cyberspace terminals that have to be completed to be able to proceed:

**Research** - in Library, the c-space is used to generate the security override code for the shields in Reactor. This 3-digit code is random for each playthrough, so while it can be brute-forced, it's faster to go here.

**Maintenance** - Terminal here unlocks access to a CPU room, which is needed to get a digit of the final code.

**Executive** - Unlocks access to Beta Grove tram, which is needed to be able to jettison it and

> for the next game to exist.

**Engineering** - Unlocks access to the antennas that are required to be destroyed to progress.