# What conditions must be met to activate the Diagnostics Log Questline on the Maintenance level in System Shock (2023)

Tags: system-shock-2023

In system Shock (2023) what in game conditions need to be met in order for you to activate the quest line for repairing the damaged isolinier systems on the maintenance level?

Comment: I edited this and your [other](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/403715/124566) post when you first posted it, but please use the correct tag `[system-shock-2023]`

Comment: Is the answer any different between the games? Also, it didn't give me the option.